# Is there a way in AzureDevOps to deploy multiple releases at once?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have multiple pipelines setup (~30), Today I need to go to Releases, select my artifact and deploy it to the needed env. This is a manual process since I don't want to deploy without approval.
Is there an option to deploy multiple artifacts, based on release branch, and request single approval for all?

Comment: Sure, you can create a release-pipeline and link as many artifacts as you like

Comment: When a release pipeline is created it already knows what artifacts it will use, it does not ask you to choose. can you share a screenshot of where you are choosing that? you might be able to set it up in a better way.

Comment: I have multiple releases pipelines. I want to be able to deploy all/some in one click. So question was how this can be done?